# Unable to add Grafana Loki datasource in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

I am following the following [grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/microservices-helm/) documentation on loki. I am unable to properly connect to my k8s clusters loki logs after installing loki, promtail, and grafana via helm charts. When I enter the http: url in Add datasources within the Grafana GUI and proceed to save & test, grafana is unable to connect to loki.

My helm commands are:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace=monitoring promtail grafana/promtail --set "loki.serviceName=loki"
helm upgrade --install loki --namespace=monitoring grafana/loki-distributed
helm install --namespace=monitoring loki-grafana grafana/grafana
```

Now I mainly am having trouble with this step and the syntax and how to debug the process:
"using the URL http://helm-installation-name-gateway.namespace.svc.cluster.local/ for Loki (with  and  replaced by the installation and namespace, respectively, of your deployment)."

I have tried all of the following URLs with no luck, any guidance would be very appreciated!

```
http://loki-grafana.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100
```

> Unable to fetch labels from Loki (Failed to call resource), please check the server logs for more details

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Though I don't see the instructions to install promtail

Comment: you're missing the -gateway part in your url fyi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
helm repo add loki https://grafana.github.io/loki/charts
helm repo update
kubectl create namespace monitoring
helm upgrade --install loki --namespace=monitoring grafana/loki-stack
helm upgrade --install grafana --namespace monitoring grafana/grafana
kubectl get secret --namespace monitoring grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo
kubectl port-forward --namespace loki service/grafana 3000:80
```

Then when you log into grafana use http://loki:3100 for the datasource url

The guide I found is here: https://medium.com/codex/setup-grafana-loki-on-local-k8s-cluster-minikube-90450e9896a8

I just skipped the minikube and ingress stuff

Comment: I originally tried this but perhaps I was using a different helm chart, but I just confirmed your answer works on a cloud setup k8s cluster as well. Do you know how to edit the helm chart to get loki also exported to grafana cloud? I just don't know how/where helm stores the configuration file to then add the grafana cloud url.

Comment: yes the difference is the loki-stack is under grafana instead of loki now. Not sure about the cloud url sorry

Comment: how to add grafana cloud: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303670/how-to-edit-a-helm-chart-loki-config-files-for-grafana-cloud

Comment: just not helm repo add loki https://grafana.github.io/loki/charts, but helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts

Answer (score 1):

#### In general

This error:

> Unable to fetch labels from Loki (Failed to call resource), please
> check the server logs for more details

Can occur due to multiple reason that are causing Grafana not not identify Loki as a datasource. 
It is really depends on the use case and setup.

#### Use case

I'll answer on the following use case:

1. Loki's Open source version.
2. Running on K8S.
3. Grafana and Loki are running on the same cluster.
4. Loki is exposed with the [Gatway component](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/concepts/#gateway).

(*) I'm also using Promtail, but this is not related to the issue (saw some answers in the internet that suggested to debug there, no need - the failure is between Grafana and Loki gateway).

#### Verifying networking setup

Please see the 2 green rectangles below:

1. We're under K8S, so the HTTP url needs to follow the pattern of: `<name-of-gateway-service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local.`  (You can try to connect with other values suggested under bullet (5) [in the docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/grafana/) or directly to the pod, but I suggest sticking with the service pattern).
2. From [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/multi-tenancy/#multi-tenancy):

> Loki defaults to running in multi-tenant mode. Multi-tenant mode is
> set in the configuration with `auth_enabled: true`. When configured with `auth_enabled: false`, Loki uses a single tenant. `The X-Scope-OrgID`
> header is not required in Loki API requests. The single tenant ID will
> be the string fake.

[image]

So, we need to add the under the `X-Scope-OrgID` header under the "Custom HTTP Headers" section or add this to the values.yaml file:

```
loki:
  auth_enabled: false
```

#### Other things that can go wrong

There are multiple reasons, especially if you're running in a non Monolithic [mode](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/fundamentals/architecture/deployment-modes/#deployment-modes), but I would suspect that if networking is OK, there might be an issue with the storage. Check the logs.